# Determine a customer's account balance via eConnect?

Tags: dynamics-gp

I work on a web application that uses eConnect to interface with Dynamics GP. Specifically, when orders are processed through our online store we submit invoices into GP using eConnect.

Some of our customers are on account and their account balance is maintained in GP. We'd like to be able to determine a customer's current account balance at the time of purchase so that we can deny the purchase if it would put their account in the red.

Is there a way, using eConnect, to determine a customer's current account balance? I've searched high and low online without much luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Although I cannot recommend a way via eConnect, you can access the customer balance via SQL by querying the [`RM00103`](http://www.gptablereference.com/2010/Table/RM00103) table.

```
SELECT CUSTBLNC as CustomerBalance
FROM RM00103
WHERE CUSTNMBR = @CustomerNo
```

Answer (score 0):

@Is there a way, using eConnect, to determine a customer's current account balance?

No, there is no eConnect to determine customer current balance.

Answer (score 0):

correct customer number field is CUSTNMBR

SELECT CUSTBLNC as CustomerBalance
FROM RM00103
WHERE **CUSTNMBR** = 'XYZ'